# How can I extract a 1d array of all combinations of Xarray coordinates?

Tags: python, indexing, coordinates, tensor, python-xarray

I'm trying to extract the coordinate values from an xarray dataset as an array the same size as the original xarray dataset where each value would be a tuple.  For example if I had a dataset with coordinates `x=[0,1]` and `y=[2,3]`, then I would like something like `np.array([(0,2), (1,2),(0,3),(1,3)])`.  This seems useless because a similar thing could be achieved using the standard `[(a,b) for a in x for b in y]`, but becomes more powerful when using xarray's `ds.where()`, and then the above function would only return a 1d array or list of coordinates where the dataset was not NaN for the given query.

Does anything like this currently exist in xarray or do I need to implement a solution myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#make some fake data
np.random.seed(123)
times = pd.date_range("2000-01-01", "2001-12-31", name="time")

annual_cycle = np.sin(2 * np.pi * (times.dayofyear.values / 365.25 - 0.28))
base = 10 + 15 * annual_cycle.reshape(-1, 1)
tmin_values = base + 3 * np.random.randn(annual_cycle.size, 3)
tmax_values = base + 10 + 3 * np.random.randn(annual_cycle.size, 3)

#Example dataset from xarray examples
ds = xr.Dataset(
    {
        "tmin": (("time", "location"), tmin_values),
        "tmax": (("time", "location"), tmax_values),
    },
    {"time": times, "location": ["IA", "IN", "IL"]},
)


### Solution
da_nans=ds.where(ds.tmin>0)

#create coordinate database
da_stacked=da_nans.stack(dim=['time','location])
nona_coords = da_stacked[da_stacked.notnull()].dim
```

The above achieves the desired result where ds.where can be any query that where already supports.  Likewise in the `.stack()` call you can specify more dimensions if you have more.